# One to one synchronization of SQLite db between app and server

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, couchdb

In my app I have a SQLite DB want to backup to server but what I want is one to one synchronization for off-line backup (e.g. standalone SQLite file instead of a centralized MySQL server, mainly performance reason and I don't need real time query)

Ideally I don't want to upload the database everytime when I need to sync, prefer only sync the changes?

Are there any existing solution for this? (I can consider using other file DB as currently I mainly use SQLite as Key-Value database)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are willing to consider using a different DB, take a look at [TouchDB-Android](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android).  This syncs a database on an Android device to a CouchDB server.  There is a related project SyncPoint, that automates setting up a database for each user.

We are using TouchDb-iOS for our product at the moment are planning work on an Android version using TouchDB-Android soon.

The development community is active.   Check out the [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Our main concern is don't want to maintain a centralized database server, just use the remote server as backup purpose. Eventually user will be very easy to download their data from our server.

Comment: I think you are describing something very similar to Apple's iCloud.  It has the ability to store SQLLite (aka CoreData) databases and sync them between devices.  CouchDB can be used to do something similar and can be used in a decentralized manner.